# C# Application crashing inside List.Enumerator

Tags: c#-4.0

I am having issues with a piece of software my company has written, it is a real-time server running as a windows service that uses RabbitMQ to interface with a WebApplication/Silverlight Client. It is crashing unexpectedly anywhere between 10 minutes and 2 weeks after starting the service. 2 errors are logged in the application event viewer (I have replaced the class and exe names with XXX):

Source: Application Error, EventId: 1000, Task: (100)

> Faulting application XXX.exe, version 0.0.1.18195, time stamp
>   0x4e4a015e, faulting module clr.dll, version 4.0.30319.1, time stamp
>   0x4ba21eeb, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset
>   0x000000000018063e, process id 0x%9, application start time 0x%10.

and

Source: .NET Runtime, EventId: 1023, Task: None

> Application: XXX.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at
>   IP 000007FEF973063E (000007FEF95B0000) with exit code 80131506.

And the following exception is being thrown. It seems to be having issues iterating over    the underlying array of a list, how this can be null is beyond me.

> XXX`1[XXX]; Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index,
>   IEnumerable`1 collection)

I have tried attaching ADPlus to the service however it slows it down so much it is unusable. As Dr. Watson is no longer available its difficult to get a memory dump, can anyone recommend any other tools that will not impact performance too much?

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the exception is occurring on a background thread in a Windows service, the service will crash. It looks like the `IEnumerable<T>` being passed into `InsertRange` is `null`.

Fix that and the problem should go away, however you are still vulnerable to crashes. I would recommend that all your background threads catch and handle exceptions. For example to start a safe threadpool thread you could do something like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        try
        {
            //...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e);
        }
    }
```